# How to Convert .txt file to .pdf

Tags: python, pdf, type-conversion

i have been trying to convert .txt to .pdf, using the code below

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
f = open("data.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=x, ln=1, align='L')
pdf.output("Data.pdf")
```

`data.txt` will be as below:
aaaaa:   4
bb:      5
cccccc:  9[data.txt_file][1]

but when convert this `data.txt` and the result `Data.pdf` will look like:

aaaaa:   4
bb:    5
cccccc:    9[Data.pdf_file][2]

the required converted file should be like same as `data.txt`.

i have also use to get the `data.txt` using this piece of code

```
letter = ['aaaaa', 'bb', 'cccccc']
number = [4, 5, 9]
for line in zip(letter, number):
     print('{:6}:    {}'.format(*line))
```

i have used tabs in print statement.
after running code the `data.txt` will be created.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Roql.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfJCU.jpg

Comment: Does data.txt have spaces or tabs for the padding? Either way though Arial isn't a monospaced font: maybe try Courier New?

Comment: actually i have saved data.txt from one of my project, i have used to generate this columns using this piece of code, for line in zip(names, number):

    print('{:38}{}'.format(*line))

Comment: I don't see anything in this piece of code, the Python FPDF code, that generates columns? In particular I can't see any code that splits the input data.txt into columns to give FPDF multiple columns to format? It looks to me like you're using the number of spaces in the middle of the line in data.txt to line up the columns.

Comment: the data.txt file itself is created using zip function.

Comment: I'm still not clear which code in the first block tells FPDF to split your text into columns by tabs in the input.

Comment: first to create a data.txt the 2nd block of code will run and then the data.txt will be read using open function and using FPDF i'll be adding pdf page and write the lines to the pdf, and finally saving the file in Data.pdf.

Comment: during this reading and writing from data,txt to Data.pdf the tabs are not printed or converted based on existing data.txt file.

Comment: there will be unsynchronized table format than data.txt in Data.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The [Aspose.Word Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python) can easily convert Text files to PDF and it honors text styling. You may try the following sample code. Put your text file on the same level for processing.

I'm a developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-python
# Import module
import asposewordscloud
import asposewordscloud.models.requests
from shutil import copyfile

# Please get your Client ID and Secret from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud.
client_id='xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

words_api = asposewordscloud.WordsApi(client_id,client_secret)
words_api.api_client.configuration.host='https://api.aspose.cloud'

filename = 'test.txt'
dest_name = 'test.PDF'
#Convert Text to PDF
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.ConvertDocumentRequest(document=open(filename, 'rb'), format='pdf')
result = words_api.convert_document(request)
copyfile(result, dest_name)
print("Result {}".format(result))
```